# Highcharts in a shiny application

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I am trying to plot a rHighchart in a shiny application and run this via Rstudio server. When I run the app the shiny page gives the error: ‘params’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Chart”. The application works perfectly in Ubuntu 12.04. but doesn't seem to work in Windows 7. I managed to get things working with renderChart2 using rCharts but I wonder if anyone has a solution for rHighchart.

```
My session info in Windows:
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rCharts_0.4.2   rHighcharts_1.0 devtools_1.5    RJSONIO_1.2-0.2 googleVis_0.5.2 shiny_0.9.1

My session info in Ubuntu:
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rHighcharts_1.0 RJSONIO_1.2-0.2 googleVis_0.5.2
[4] rCharts_0.4.2   shiny_0.9.1
```

The code for the application is below, with the only difference that in Windows I call the Highcharts JS library within showOutput using "Highcharts" instead of highcharts":

```
  **ui.R**
   library("shiny") 
   require("rCharts") 
   mainPanel(   
    tabsetPanel( 
     tabPanel("Charts", 
      showOutput ("radar", "highcharts"), 
    ),


    **server. R**

    library(rHighcharts)

    output$bar<- renderChart({ 
    a <- rHighcharts:::Chart$new()   
    a$title(text = paste0("Indicators by Country Year: ", input$year) ) 
    a$subtitle(text = "Selected list of indicators") 
    a$xAxis(categories = rownames(passData())) 
    a$yAxis(title = list(text = "Indicator value")) 
    a$data(passData()[input$indicator],type = "column") 
    return(a) 
    })
```

Thanks for your help!

Juan

Comment: The `rHighcharts` project was merged into `rCharts`. You should use the `rCharts` package instead now. Your example is not reproducible. What is `passData`?

Comment: Thanks!Ok, then it is probably better to use rCharts instead. "passData" is just a dataframe with a list of indicators and their values.

Comment: I have a similar issue and came to this Q&A: is rCharts supposed to be available for R 3.1.0?

Comment: Yes it is working without problems. I use rCharts version 0.4.2 both in Windows and Linux.